# Plotting loss vs epoch

Tags: python, validation, plot, google-colaboratory

I want to plot the loss vs epoch graph to my Crowd Counting network training code; however, the network is trained for 270 epochs out of 500 epochs and i am resuming the training using a checkpoint. Can it be done in this stage of the training and how can do it ? what code should be added to the training python script so that i can plot this ?
I am using google Colab for the training.

Training code:

```
def main():
    global args,best_prec1

    best_prec1 = 1e6
    args = parser.parse_args()
    #args = [TRAIN, VAL]
    args.lr = 3e-8
    args.batch_size    = 1
    args.decay         = 0.9
    args.start_epoch   = 0
    args.epochs = 6
    args.workers = 4
    args.seed = int(time.time())
    args.print_freq = 4
    newargs=(','.join(args.train_json[0]))
    with open(newargs, 'r') as outfile:
        train_list = json.load(outfile)
    with open(args.val_json, 'r') as outfile:
        val_list = json.load(outfile)
    print("done4")
    torch.cuda.manual_seed(args.seed)

    model = CANNet()

    model = model.cuda()

    criterion = nn.MSELoss(size_average=False).cuda()

    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), args.lr,
                                    weight_decay=args.decay)
    
    ########################################################

    checkpoint = torch.load('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/)
    model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
    optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer']) 
    epoch = checkpoint['epoch']
    args.start_epoch = checkpoint['epoch']

    ########################################################

    for epoch in range(args.start_epoch, args.epochs):
        train(train_list, model, criterion, optimizer, epoch)
        prec1 = validate(val_list, model, criterion)

        is_best = prec1 < best_prec1
        best_prec1 = min(prec1, best_prec1)
        print(' * best MAE {mae:.3f} '
              .format(mae=best_prec1))
        save_checkpoint({
            'state_dict': model.state_dict(),
            'model': model.state_dict(),
            'optimizer': optimizer.state_dict(),
            'epoch': epoch
        }, is_best)

def train(train_list, model, criterion, optimizer, epoch):

    losses = AverageMeter()
    batch_time = AverageMeter()
    data_time = AverageMeter()

    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        dataset.listDataset(train_list,
                       shuffle=True,
                       transform=transforms.Compose([
                       transforms.ToTensor(),transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                                     std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
                   ]),
                       train=True,
                       seen=model.seen,
                       batch_size=args.batch_size,
                       num_workers=args.workers),
        batch_size=args.batch_size)
    print('epoch %d, processed %d samples, lr %.10f' % (epoch, epoch * len(train_loader.dataset), args.lr))

    model.train()
    end = time.time()

    for i,(img, target)in enumerate(train_loader):
        data_time.update(time.time() - end)

        img = img.cuda()
        img = Variable(img)
        output = model(img)[:,0,:,:]

        target = target.type(torch.FloatTensor).cuda()
        target = Variable(target)

        loss = criterion(output, target)

        losses.update(loss.item(), img.size(0))
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        batch_time.update(time.time() - end)
        end = time.time()

        if i % args.print_freq == 0:
            print('Epoch: [{0}][{1}/{2}]\t'
                  'Time {batch_time.val:.3f} ({batch_time.avg:.3f})\t'
                  'Data {data_time.val:.3f} ({data_time.avg:.3f})\t'
                  'Loss {loss.val:.4f} ({loss.avg:.4f})\t'
                  .format(
                   epoch, i, len(train_loader), batch_time=batch_time,
                   data_time=data_time, loss=losses))

def validate(val_list, model, criterion):
    print ('begin val')
    val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    dataset.listDataset(val_list,
                   shuffle=False,
                   transform=transforms.Compose([
                       transforms.ToTensor(),transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                                     std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
                   ]),  train=False),
    batch_size=1)

    model.eval()

    mae = 0

    for i,(img, target) in enumerate(val_loader):
        h,w = img.shape[2:4]
        h_d = int(h/2)
        w_d = int(w/2)
        img_1 = Variable(img[:,:,:h_d,:w_d].cuda())
        img_2 = Variable(img[:,:,:h_d,w_d:].cuda())
        img_3 = Variable(img[:,:,h_d:,:w_d].cuda())
        img_4 = Variable(img[:,:,h_d:,w_d:].cuda())
        density_1 = model(img_1).data.cpu().numpy()
        density_2 = model(img_2).data.cpu().numpy()
        density_3 = model(img_3).data.cpu().numpy()
        density_4 = model(img_4).data.cpu().numpy()

        pred_sum = density_1.sum()+density_2.sum()+density_3.sum()+density_4.sum()

        mae += abs(pred_sum-target.sum())

    mae = mae/len(val_loader)
    print(' * MAE {mae:.3f} '
              .format(mae=mae))

    return mae

class AverageMeter(object):
    """Computes and stores the average and current value"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self.val = 0
        self.avg = 0
        self.sum = 0
        self.count = 0

    def update(self, val, n=1):
        self.val = val
        self.sum += val * n
        self.count += n
        self.avg = self.sum / self.count

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

should this be added to the validation part of the training code ?